# Is it possible for loadmore in Android app widget listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

I have implemented listview in app widget control. Now I want to implement load more when scrolled to the last item of the listview. I have no idea to do this.

Could you please suggest me any idea to do this? Is it possible to add scroll listener for app widget listview  in AppWidgetProvider class, and how to update the listview items after getting data from load more data call from web service.

Comment: "Is it possible to add scroll listener for app widget listview in AppWidgetProvider class" -- no. The only way that I can think of to do something like this is to is to have your `RemoteViewsFactory` detect when it is being asked for a `position` near the end of your data, and then kick off the work to load more data. Then, call `updateAppWidget()` on the `AppWidgetManager` with a fresh `RemoteViews`. I suspect that the UX will not work out very well (e.g., the list will scroll back to the top after you "load more").

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. I will check it and let you know.